# pselect gets interrupted occationally

Tags: c, sockets, select, udp

First and formost, I didn't have the reputation to tag this as being a question about 'pselect', so I went with 'select'.

I use pselect to handle timeouts on an UDP socket. The code looks as follows:

```
UDP_STATUS udp_socket_recv(udp_socket_t* p_sock, int* p_bytes_rcvd)
{
    int res = 0;
    fd_set fds;
    struct timespec timeout;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(p_sock->m_socket, &fds);

    if (p_sock->m_timeout == NULL) {
        res = pselect(p_sock->m_socket + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    } else {
        timeout.tv_sec = p_sock->m_timeout->tv_sec;
        timeout.tv_msec = p_sock->m_timeout->tv_usec * 1000;
        res = pselect(p_sock->m_socket + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL);
    }

    if (res == 0)
        return UDP_TIMEOUT;
    else if (res == -1) {
        printf("pselect error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); /* Sometimes we end up here */
        return UDP_FAILURE;
    }

    res = recvfrom(p_sock->m_socket, ..); /* etc etc */
}
```

Now, the above works just fine in the *vast majority* of cases (although I might have misstyped something as I don't have access to copy/paste). pselect does however sometimes return -1, with the strerror(errno) call printing "Interrupted system call".

I'm not even sure this is how you want to do socket timeouts, I can't even remember how I came up with this solution...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it is only an interrupted system call. Just call pselect() again, and mybe it will succeed this time. BTW `if (p_sock->m_timeout == NULL) {` You are only calling pselect if timeout is NULL. You probably want to call pselect() too in the `else { ... } ` case.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I forgot about the pselect in the else clause.

Regarding doing the call to pselect again, what if it fails again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EINTR / *interrupted system call* is not an error condition, just something that happened (a signal was delivered and maybe handled) while your program whas blocked inside the system call. You can ignore it and simply loop, like here: (the below program is not optimal, only a demonstration of how you can handle the EINTR)

```
UDP_STATUS udp_socket_recv(udp_socket_t* p_sock, int* p_bytes_rcvd)
{
int res = 0;
fd_set fds;
struct timespec timeout;

FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(p_sock->m_socket, &fds);

while(1) {
  if (p_sock->m_timeout == NULL) {
      res = pselect(p_sock->m_socket + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  } else {
      timeout.tv_sec = p_sock->m_timeout->tv_sec;
      timeout.tv_msec = p_sock->m_timeout->tv_usec * 1000;
      res = pselect(p_sock->m_socket + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL);
  }

  if (res > 0) break;
  if (res == 0)
    return UDP_TIMEOUT;

  switch(errno) {
  case EINTR: continue;
  default:
    printf("pselect error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); /* Sometimes we end up here */
    return UDP_FAILURE;
   }
 }

res = recvfrom(p_sock->m_socket, ..); /* etc etc */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle `EINTR`.  `EAGAIN` is a rather different beast; it means that no data was ready for reading.

Comment: At your service! Thanks. (Yes, I had them mixed-up!)

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks alot to all of you, this saved my day (and probably even week). :)

Comment: I can advise you to read WR Stevens. This is really basic stuff (even though I gooofed up initially) The possible error returns are also also listed in the man pages for select() and pselect() Just choose what your program should do in the particular case, and maybe add another case to the switch.

Answer (score 0):

No, really, just restart the system call.  If it fails again, that means your process received another signal.  `EINTR`, as far as I'm aware, is largely an implementation artefact from early Unix systems so that they could deliver signals while blocking system calls were in progress.  Lots of ink has been spilled on whether it was a smart or a stupid design decision, but the upshot of it all is that code making blocking system calls needs to retry when the calls fail with `EINTR`.